# Messages view is broken on mobile

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, mobile-web, design

Opening the messaging view on mobile (OnePlus 6t) leads to an unusable view. Texts overlap and buttons are misplaced. A screenshot is worth more than a thousand words.

[image: Screenshot of message]

Image anonymized for obvious reasons.

Comment: Was the Jobs site made compatible with mobile?  I don't remember it being done that way but that'd be an issue if it wasn't.

Comment: Other jobs pages seem to work fine. I was unaware of the fact that it was a "jobs message". I was under the understanding that there was a generic messaging system.

Comment: As far as I know it, *that* page is only ever used for Jobs.  The rest of the site has no notion of "message" in a normal context, and even then that'd only be for moderator-related messages, which I don't believe take you to a specific page like *that*.